# Regular Expression to match a name with salution of Mr. or Mrs

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, expression

Google isn’t being much help, so I’m hoping someone on here could help me?

`preg_match(‘^(MR|MRS)./s[a-z]/s[a-z]$/i’, $_POST[‘fullname’])`

I need a regular expression that allows a name with the salutation of Mr. or Mrs. followed by two text strings separated by any number of spaces. Mine isn’t working and I have no idea why. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would you be expecting an input string like this: "Mr. Wood said no". Because if so there's more to be done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is invalid syntax, it needs to start and end with the same delimiter:

```
preg_match(‘/^mrs?\.\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+$/i’, $_POST[‘fullname’])
............^..........................^
```

Know however that this is a fragile regex to use - it is *not* uncommon to have multiple first names, to use a middle name, or to have a double barreled surname, or to have accents in your name - e.g. Zöe.

### regex explanation

```
/ - start regex
^mr - string starts with mr
s? - optional "s"
\. - period
\s+ - 0 or more whitespace chars (tabs or spaces)
[a-z]+ - 0 or more letters
\s+ - 0 or more whitespace chars (tabs or spaces)
[a-z]+ - 0 or more letters
$ - end of string
/ - end of regex
i - whole regex is case insensitive.
```

Comment: you should escape the dot and made it optional

Comment: Thank you! This one works. I know it should allow other characters, but those were the rules I had to follow.

Answer (score 1):

> [A-Z]?[a-zA-Z]{1,30}[ ]?[.]?[']?[ ]?[a-zA-Z]{1,30}[ ]?[.]?[']?[
>   ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,30}[ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,30}

Works For the following names:

- Dr. James Mathew
- James Mathew
- Dr . James Mathew John
- Mr.James
- O'Really

and many more...

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
preg_match("/^(MR|MRS)\.?(\s*\w*)+$/i", $_POST[‘fullname’])
```

If the dot isn't optionnal.. delete the "?"

Comment: Would that match the trailing dot at the end of MR. ?

Comment: Yeah thanks, forgot that... added the . after MR (Thanks for the -1 ...)

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't -1 your answer - I tend to only downvote answers when they're obviously massively incorrect. If it's something I think you might just have overlooked, I'll just add a comment instead.

Comment: I downvoted - You're still missing a leading delimiter for the regex - making the answer invalid syntax; running it would just throw an error. Plus, using * means that it matches "mr." - which isn't a name.